# How to move the public folder container from the First Administrative Group if Exchange 2003 is no longer there?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, exchange-2003, public-folders

This is an Exchange 2007 organization, which was migrated from Exchange 2003; when the last Exchange 2003 server was removed, nobody bothered moving the public folder hierarchy object from the default "First Administrative Group" to the new "Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)", which is ordinarily done from an Exchange 2003 server's administrative console before removing it. Now Exchange 2003 is gone, and I can't find any utility that can perform this move.

How can this be done when there are no more Exchange 2003 servers in the organization?

Comment: So you didn't replicate the public folder data over to the new 07 server before decomissioning?  Or you replicated the data over, but haven't updated the hierarchy?  I've got a bunch of links that may or may not help, I'm just trying to understand the problem better...

Comment: PF **data** has been replicated, and the PF store on the Exchange 2003 server has been decommissioned (as had been the server, too). But the main folder container in AD, which is usually stored under "First Administrative Group", has not been moved from there to the new Exchange Administrative Group. This can clearly be seen from AD Sites & Services and/or from ADSIEdit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up installing the Exchange 2003 administrative tools on a Windows Server 2003 computer and moving the container using Exchange 2003's System Manager, as would be the case in a standard 2003-2007 transition.